# Write and read array data in CSV row

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm facing a problem and I can't solve it: I need to write a CSV file to process the CSV data. I'm doing it like this:

```rb
payload = {name: 'Dimitrius', errors: ['error1'] }
CSV.open(file_name, "a+") do |csv|
  csv.add_row(payload.values)
end
```

The CSV file was created and populated like a charm \o/
But, the array of `errors` in the CSV file was a 'string':

```rb
csv_text = File.read(file_name)
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, headers: false)
puts csv # [["Dimitrius", "[\"error1\"]"]
```

The problem is, I must create so much 'workarounds' to transform the string `"[\"error1\"]"` into a valid array :(

My question is, this is the correct way to work with array values in CSV files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to get along with this problem :)
Instead of initializing my payload to write in the CSV file with an array, I initialize it with a string with a separator:

```rb
payload = {name: 'Dimitrius', errors: ['error1', 'error2', 'error3'].join('|') }
CSV.open(file_name, "a+") do |csv|
  csv.add_row(payload.values)
end
```

Now, my CSV file will generate this result:

```rb
csv_text = File.read(file_name)
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, headers: false)
puts csv # [["Dimitrius", "error1|error2|error3"]
```

And, I can easy transform this string `"error1|error2|error3"` into an array executing a `.split` like the follwing:

```rb
errors = "error1|error2|error3".split('|')
errors # ['error1', 'error2', 'error3']
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution to work with arrays in CSV, but to my case works because the error string will never contain the operator `|`.

If someone has another idea, I will be glad to discuss about :)

Answer (score 2):

I've stolen Dimitrius' idea of using a reserved character to denote an array and expanded on that by creating a custom data converter to convert strings containing the reserved character to arrays, the elements of which are then converted to appropriate data types.

**Data**

```
arr = [{ name: 'Dimitrius', errors: ['e1', 3, 4.1] },
       { name: 'Wilma',     errors: ['f1', 7, 9.5] }]
```

**Write the CSV file**

```
require 'csv'

FName = 't.csv'
```

I've assumed that if a substring between commas in the CSV file contains a specified *reserved character* it denotes an array, with the reserved character separating elements of the array.

```
RESERVED_CHAR = '|'

keys = arr.first.keys
  #=> [:name, :errors] 
rows = arr.map(&:values)
  #=> [["Dimitrius", ["e1", 3, 4.1]],
  #    ["Wilma",     ["f1", 7, 9.5]]]

CSV.open(FName, "wb") do |csv|
  csv << keys
  rows.each { |name,arr| csv << [name, arr.join(RESERVED_CHAR)] }
end
  #=> [["Dimitrius", ["e1", 3, 4.1]], ["Wilma", ["f1", 7, 9.5]]]
```

Let's see what was written.

```
File.read(FName).each_line { |line| p line }
"name,errors\n"
"Dimitrius,e1|3|4.1\n"
"Wilma,f1|7|9.5\n"
```

**Read the CSV file**

The [CSV](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class has six built-in data converters (look under "Constants"). One may, however, add additional converters as needed. These convert values in the rows, but not the headers.

```
require 'csv'
FName = 't.csv'
RESERVED_CHAR = '|'

CSV::Converters[:array] = ->(v) do
  if v.include?(RESERVED_CHAR)
    v.split(RESERVED_CHAR).map do |e|
      case e
      when /\A\-?\d+\z/
        e.to_i
      when /\A\-?\d+\.\d+\z/
        e.to_f
      else
        e
      end
    end
  else
    v
  end
end
```

We may now read the CSV file into a `CSV::Table` object:

```
tbl = CSV.read(FName, headers: true, converters: :array)
  #=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:3>
```

We can use this to extract the headers and rows:

```
headers, *body = tbl.to_a
  #=> [["name", "errors"],
  #    ["Dimitrius", ["e1", 3, 4.1]],
  #    ["Wilma", ["f1", 7, 9.5]]] 
headers
  #=> ["name", "errors"] 
body
  #=> [["Dimitrius", ["e1", 3, 4.1]],
  #    ["Wilma",     ["f1", 7, 9.5]]]
```

or individual columns:

```
tbl["name"]
  #=> ["Dimitrius", "Wilma"] 
tbl["errors"]
  #=> [["e1", 3, 4.1],
  #    ["f1", 7, 9.5]]
```

Note that the values in the arrays have been converted as desired, and the headers are now strings. If they are to be symbols that would require a separate step at the end.